# URL address availability - auto verification

Tags: verification

I have an input that's in form. I enter the URL adress into this input, click sumbit, and below it shows if this address is available or not. This is done.

Now I want to make this information show up **automatically** (without clicking submit), after making a change in the input? I would also like the value in the input to not disappear after checking. How can I do that?

I would like it to look more or less like this, but instead of email correctness, URL availability - https://youtu.be/HzJngc-Se9Q

```html
<form action="" method="GET" name="form1" id="form1">
            <div id="custom-search-input">
                <div class="adress-div">
                    <input type="text" id="ok" name="domain" maxlenght="30" class="adress" pattern="(.{1,})?([.]{1})?.+[.]{1}.+" placeholder="np. www.page.com" title="Enter URL adress." autocomplete="off" required/>
                    <br>
                        <input type="submit" class="button2" value="Check!">
                </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        <?php
 error_reporting(0);
 if(isset($_GET['domain'])){
     $domain = $_GET['domain'];
     $godaddycheck = 'https://in.godaddy.com/domains/searchresults.aspx?checkAvail=1&tmskey=&domainToCheck='.$domain.'';
     $namecomcheck = 'https://www.name.com/domain/search/'.$domain.'';
     $registercomcheck = 'http://www.register.co,    m/domain/search/wizard.rcmx?searchDomainName='.$domain.'&searchPath=Default&searchTlds=';
 if ( gethostbyname($domain) != $domain ) {
  echo "<br><br><h1 style='color: #e30000;'><b>$domain</b> not available.</h1>";
 }
 else {
  echo "<br><br><h1 style='color: #00e339;'><b>$domain</b> available.</h1><h2>
  </h2>";
 }
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible doing only with PHP.

You will need to do that with JavaScript. Therefore you need to

1. listen on an input change for your `<input>`field
2. Send the value of the input field with AJAX (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) to a PHP script, which then validates the domain
3. Fetch the response and display it to the user

---

But there are a lot of tutorials out there, how to do that. For example: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp